# HttpPost with StringEntity having special characters like ®, seeing ¿½` instead of ®

Tags: java, character-encoding, apache-httpclient-4.x

I need to use special characters for `stringentity` as below.

```
DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(url);
HttpEntity entity = new StringEntity("test®");
httpPost.setEntity(entity);
httpPost.setHeader("Accept-Encoding", "UTF-8");

HttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(httpPost);
BufferedReader reader =  new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader((response.getEntity().getContent())));
while ((reader.readLine()) != null) {
    System.out.println (reader.readLine());
}
reader.close();
```

The output contains `testï¿½` instead of `test®` in the response.

Comment: Define "seeing" - if you're using `System.out.prinln` are you sure your console uses the same encoding as the data you received?

Comment: Are your source code files also in UTF-8?

Comment: The `StringEntity` uses `ISO_8859_1` for the content charset. You have to use another constructor which allows you to pass in the encoding. `new StringEntity("test®", "UTF-8")` should do the trick.

Comment: Another day, another person confused by character encodings.

Comment: @cole I wouldn't hold this against them in this case. It isn't immediately clear at which point the content is serialized.

Comment: Thanks. This is working. new StringEntity("test®", "UTF-8") did the trick

Answer (score 49, accepted):

Change to:

```
    HttpEntity entity = new StringEntity("test®", "UTF-8");
```

Comment: Thanks. This is working. new StringEntity("test®", "UTF-8") did the trick

Comment: Above solution is not working for me. It is showing [0xc3][0x83][0xe2][0x80][0x93] for Ö  character. I using HttpEntity params =new StringEntity(xmlfileString,"UTF-8");

Comment: @Brijesh Are you using System.out.prinln to read the data? Please, check the encoding used by the "tool" you're using to check the value.

Answer (score 3):

Instead of **StringEntity**, I'm using **ByteArrayEntity**:

```
String string = "ã@í";
HttpEntity httpEntity = new ByteArrayEntity(string.getBytes("UTF-8"));
request.addHeader("Content-type", "application/xml;charset=UTF-8");
request.setEntity(httpEntity);
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I was already using the answer code, but adding this did the trick (I saw it in the question text)

```
httpPost.setHeader("Accept-Encoding", "UTF-8");
```